# Application.Caller to Range

Tags: excel, excel-udf, vba

I have a function which includes the below line;

```
targetRange.Offset(0, -2).Value = "=validate_pointLoad()"
```

This cell then references a new function which is below;

```
Public Function validate_pointLoad() As String

    Dim CallerAddr As String

    With Application.Caller
        CallerAddr = .Address
    End With

    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = Application.Caller
    targetRange.Ofsett(0, 10).Value = "Enter Required Data"

    validate_pointLoad = "FAIL"

End Function
```

I need to change the value of a cell that is 10 columns to the right of the cell that called the function but I can't get this to work. The value of the cell that called the function becomes `#VALUE!`

I've tried a few variations of the above code but can't get anything to work, does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: A function called from a cell can't change the value of cells. Also, you've misspelled "Offset". If the purpose is just to display a message in a cell when another cell is populated then you can do that with a cell formula.

Comment: Why not just change `targetRange.Offset(0, -2).Value = "=validate_pointLoad()"` to `targetRange.Offset(0, -2).Value = "FAIL": targetRange.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Enter Required Data"`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies - the function does more than just change the value of another cell, I just haven't written that out yet as this wasn't working. I guess i'll have to think of another way